# How to split docker file from monolithic deployment

Tags: java, node.js, docker, containers

In a single docker file I use to run Node and Java for the following:

1. run test script
2. run java executable (to bundle screenshots)
3. run my application

My understanding from the documentation is that this is bad practice, in the sense that this is a 'monolithic' deployment.  I am supposed to split this in separate images based on the individual tasks.  So, presumably, I would have 3 docker files.

Dockerfile 1: test script

```
FROM node:8
RUN node --version

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq libgconf-2-4

# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium work
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget --no-install-recommends \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst ttf-freefont \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl \
    && rm -rf /src/*.deb

# project repo

RUN git clone ...
WORKDIR /myApp/  
RUN npm install

RUN npm i puppeteer

CMD ["node", "test.ts"]
```

Dockerfile 2: Java executable (bundle images)

```
FROM openjdk
RUN git clone -b ...

WORKDIR /myApp/


CMD ["java -jar", "ImageTester.jar"]
```

Dockerfile 3: Run app

```
FROM node:8
RUN node --version

RUN git clone -b ...

WORKDIR /myApp/  
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 9999
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The question is, how does one exactly do this?  How is a non monolithic deployment implemented in my case?  How does one run 3 docker images inside one project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use docker-compose. In your docker-compose.yml file, you'll have 3 services pointing to the 3 different dockerfiles.

Ex:

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
  images:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.images
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.app
```

Comment: Aha, I see.  But, does that mean each one of these is a separate container?

Comment: Yes, definitely, so to get them all to share the same working directory, you'll have to mount it as a volume. Doing so in compose is pretty easy.

Comment: Ok right, all images in same working directory.  But, 'mount it as a volume', what exactly does that mean?

Comment: A volume in Docker is a directory that is exposed to the host from the container (similar to how ports work in Docker with the -p switch). You can choose whether the exposed directory is managed by Docker (it will be located in some seemingly random location on the host machine in a docker sub-directory), or managed by the host OS (just a plain old folder on your machine). Read up on Docker volumes, but the syntax you're looking for is <full path to dir on host>:<full path to dir in container>. You can do more complicated mounts that use dirs copied into the images, but this will start you off

Comment: Ok, the gears in my head are starting to turn.  Now I have 3 docker images and so 3 containers, but they all need to share the same working directory, as this is one deployment.  This is done by configuring my compose file to mount as a volume which I understand it to mean mapping my local project directory to the directory in the container <local machine directory>:<container directory>.  This is somehow specified in the compose file.  Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that's right. [Here's the docker-compose.yml file documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/), and [here's the docker-compose command documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/)